# Simple radio button unit test using gwtmockito/mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, gwtmockito

I wanted to write a simple unit test avoiding GWTTeseCase for an extension of a radio button.

This is the composite

```
public class DeselectableRadioButton extends RadioButton {

private Boolean backingValue;

private final class RadioButtonClickHandler implements ClickHandler {

    public RadioButtonClickHandler(Boolean value) {
        backingValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) event.getSource();
        if (!backingValue) {
            button.setValue(true);
            backingValue = true;
        } else {
            button.setValue(false);
            backingValue = false;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor creates radio button with name and value
 * 
 * @param name The name to be assigned to the radio button
 * @param value The default value to be given to the radio button
 */
public DeselectableRadioButton(String name, Boolean value) {
    super(name);
    this.setValue(value);
    setupHandlers(value);
}

private void setupHandlers(Boolean value) {
    addClickHandler(new RadioButtonClickHandler(value));
}
```

}

I was looking at some examples with GWTMockito such as:
https://gist.github.com/nbuesing/7090529

But it doesn't seem possible with the current implementation of the widget I have?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question because you're not writing what you tried or why you think it's not possible. But why create an de-selectable radio button? Ctrl-Click already does this, and it probably not intuitive for the user.

Comment: Also even without testing it I can tell you your code isn't going to work. The backing value is only set on clicking. However, if you combine radio buttons in a group and one of the buttons is clicked the state of the other buttons will change, but no click event is given, so you're backing value won't change for those buttons, so when the user clicks on them the button will set accordingly to the backing value and not the actual state.